# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded : JavaScript error when showing thick-box on click function on multiple divisions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, stack, addeventlistener

I have a table displayed on the page with item details displayed  . When total cells are less than 5K then there is no JavaScript error but when table has 6K cells or more then stack exceeding error occurs and JavaScript doesn't works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').click(function (e) {
        var Elem = e.target;
        var itemgroup = $(Elem).attr('rel');
        var itemid = $(Elem).attr('itemno');

        if (Elem.className == 'additem') {
            tb_show('Add',
                'add_item.html' + '?&itemid=' + itemid + '&itemgrp=' + itemgroup + '&TB_iframe=true&height=420width=500',
                '/images/items.jpg');

        } else if (Elem.className == 'showsoldqty') {
            tb_show('Show',
                'show_sold_qty.html' + '?&itemid=' + itemid + '&itemgrp=' + itemgroup + '&TB_iframe=true&height=420width=500',
                '/images/items.jpg');
        }
    });
```

The table structure is as mentioned below with one row as sample (the column in this row is being repeated and displayed more than 6K times dynamically using php code ) :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="additem" rel="G1" itemno="21">Add Item</div>
            <div class="showsoldqty" rel="G2" itemno="22">Show Sold Quantity</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How are you constructing the table?

Comment: @Bart : sir, the table is constructed dynamically using php code

Comment: What are the functions on the stack? And please post their code.

Comment: @Bergi : sir,  The error console in chrome just shows this error : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Would you post the code for `tb_show()`?

Comment: @cfs : sir,  tb_show is the thickbox jquery which am using

Comment: When does the error occur? On page load, when you click something...?

Comment: the page loads .the whole table gets displayed , but the jquery doesn't , it hangs .....all jquery codes like hover etc.  , the click do not work

Comment: @cfs : sir, this is the thickbox code : http://jsfiddle.net/k6QY3/1/

Comment: there really isn't enough information here to identify an issue. do you have other jQuery code on this page? If so would you post that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37652/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-cfs)